# How does Unity use C# as a scripting language?

Tags: c#, scripting, mono

To my knowledge, thus far, I have thought that C# is and has always been a compiled language. I have recently started studying Unity3d and noticed that they give C# as an option for scripting and interacting with game objects through their API (along with JavaScript and a couple of other alternatives).

How is this done? Is C# actually being executed or is this an abstraction that is being converted to a different scripting language under the covers? It seems to me that there is some sort of interpretation going on for this functionality.

Comment: What are scripting languages?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Scripting_languages languages interpreted at runtime rather than compile time.

Comment: But JavaScript is compiled before being executed 99% of the time, and some Python implementations too. C(++) can be interpreted. I think that the terminology is flawed, as you're not talking about a property of the language, but the way you use it. But it seems that's not really important for the question...

Comment: "compiled" or "scripted" is not the property of programming language. When you are implementing the language specification, you can decide whether you want to "compile" it or "interpret" it.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is off. I have always understood anything that is interpreted at runtime to being "scripted" (as it is not compiled.. ie PHP cannot be compiled) and anything that is compiled prior to being ran as being "compiled". I also thought that JavaScript was interpreted at runtime (like PHP). At what point does JavaScript get compiled?.. there is no compiler for it. (serious question, not being a smart ass)

Comment: That being said, what I have always interpreted as a "scripting language" is the basis of this definition. Perhaps the vocab should have been "interpreted" but I have always seen them one in the same. http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/scripting_language.html

Answer (score 16):

Unity is using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) behind the scenes. Every time you make a change to your C#/UnityScript scripts it recompiles the code almost instantly.

If you look in the data directory of a standalone unity player, you can see it has compiled all the scripts into Assembly-CSharp.dll, or similar.

So yes, the C# is being compiled.

Comment: Ah I see the .dll now in the data directory. This clears things up.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question and not turning it into a pompous semantic arm-wrestling match

Comment: @BrandonClapp if this answer solved your question, please mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this, but how does Unity handle the loading and unloading of the compiled DLL in the editor? Or should I start a new question?

Answer (score -2):

C# is an object oriented programming language - it needs to be compiled before ran. Just because it is widely used in Unity3d, don't let its ease and flexibility fool you.

Comment: So because it is object oriented, it needs to be compiled?

Comment: No, not because it's a OOP. It needs to be compiled because it's a programming language. Script languages do not require to be compiled and are used in a runtime environment. In the context of Unity, back in Unity 2.0 Javascript was able to ran and changed during runtime. I don't think that functionality exists anymore.

Answer (score -4):

First, scripting languages are not necessarily interpreted languages. Some scripting languages such as Lua and Python can be either JIT-compiled or interpreted.

And, as for the question itself: because C# is a scripting language, but Microsoft does a good job on making it not look as such.

C# has everything a scripting language needs: dynamic typing, JIT-compiling rather than static compiling, runs in a virtual machine...