# Does C# affect performance in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

similar question :[How does Unity use C# as a scripting language?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51350/how-does-unity-use-c-as-a-scripting-language)
In Unity , some functions like Update , run per object , per frame.
so , is .Net framework involved at runtime ?
could it affect performance?

Comment: If you are referring to a already answered question please try to use the answers provided. If you can´t resolve your issue post more specific informations about your problem. This question is very open and broad and won´t work well with the Q&A style of stackexchange (see: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Compared to what? In what case?

Compared to Boo or UnityScript, scripting Unity in C# [can be faster](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/29778-newby-performance-question-which-language-is-best), but the difference will probably be quite marginal.

Compared to C/C++, C# may be slower in many cases, but since the languages operate at different levels, making a useful comparison is very difficult. As Unity cannot be scripted in C/C++, you would get more substantial performance differences because of the engine switch, rather than the language switch.

**However**, in the vast majority of programming, algorithmic choices have much more impact  in performance than language choices: for arbitrarily big random arrays, BubbleSort in ultra-optimized assembly will *always* lose to QuickSort, even if written in Brainfuck.

**However**, when writing software, ease of writing, simplicity, clarity and understandability are usually much more important than performance. Basing your language choice exclusively on performance issues is not usually a wise idea.

So, if this is your first time using Unity, I would like to recommend you use the language you're most comfortable with, and if you find any specific performance problems you can detect by profiling, you should focus on fixing that specific problem, first by trying a better algorithm, and only as a last resort, by doing it in a different language which you know will give you better performance in that specific problem.